# Creating n number of child processes from one parent process

Tags: c

I was trying to create `n`(say `n=3`) child processes from a single parent process but couldn't reach a solution. I have tried this code:

```
for(i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    fork();
}
```

But unfortunately it is creating 7 child processes.

Comment: @anastaciu but then it will be wrong info

Comment: The return value from `fork` tells you whether the code is running in the parent or in the child. The child should not continue the loop.

Comment: Are you sure that it's not 7 processes in total?

Comment: @anastaciu when `i=0`, parent create `child1`, then when `i=1` parent and `child1` creates `child2` and `child3`, then when `i=2`, parent, `child1`, `child2`, and `child3` create `child4`,`child5`,`child6`,`child7` ---> totak 7 child processes

Comment: @AgrudgeAmicus, bath math I guess, I reckon, you're right.

Comment: `fork(); fork();` (if all ok) now you have the original process, 1 children, 2 grand children

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to put a check so that only parent could create child processes, here is the example to do it:

```
pid_t pid1;

 pid1 = getpid();

 for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
      if(pid1 == getpid())
           fork();
```

Comment: It doesn't seem very efficient to call ```getpid()``` four times when the return value of ```fork()``` tells you what you need to know.

Answer (score 3):

This happens because each of the children continues executing the loop from where it was when it forked:

- The root process forks 3 children: `a`, `b`, `c`
- `a` sees `i=0` and creates children `d` and `e`
- `d` sees `i=1` and creates `f`
- `b` sees `i=1` and creates `g`
- `c`, `e`, `f` and `g` see `i=2` and just exit the loop.

That makes 7 children. You need to check the return value of `fork()` to make sure that you're in the parent process:

```
if (!fork()) {  // returns 0 to the child
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need first to consider that all those forks return both in the parent and the child, so they all create three processes in a three level binary tree (leading to seven final processes)

The right way to do is to check the parent's return value, which is:

- `-1` in case of error (you must always check) you need to check `errno` to get an idea of why the `fork()` failed.
- `0` in this case you are the child, you have not to `fork()` again, or you will end with lots of processes.  I just pause for 10 seconds, then die in the sample code below.
- `> 0` to allow the parent to know the child's pid (and save it to know which of the children `exit()`ed on each `wait()` return).  (you are the parent process)

this leads to some code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) { /* repeat five times */
        int child_pid;
        if ((child_pid = fork()) < 0) {  /* error */
            perror("fork");
            exit(1);
        } else if (child_pid > 0) { /* we are the parent */
            printf("Parent, forked child %d with pid = %d\n",
                    i, child_pid);
            /* we continue with the next child until no more
             * children to start, then we will wait(2) for them
             * all, before exiting. */
        } else { /* we are the child */
            /* our pid is got from getpid(2) system call */
            printf("I'm the %d child, with pid = %d\n",
                    i, getpid());
            sleep(10); /* do something useful, like sleeping :) */
            exit(0); /* and exit */
        }
        /* the only process that gets here is the parent, as the child
         * does an exit in its block above */
        /* go for next child */
    }
    printf("... now, we need to wait until no children are alive\n");
    int child_exit_pid;
    while ((child_exit_pid = wait(NULL)) >= 0) {  /* wait until we get an error */
        printf("Child with pid == %d exit\n",
                child_exit_pid);
    }
    printf("Parent exit after all children died\n");
}
```